# Boxplotting count data with a continuous variable in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a problem while boxplotting count data. I have a dataset of 420 study sites with bird observations and elevation data of each site. Study sites are in rows and different bird species and elevation in columns. My goal is to boxplot occurrence of different bird species in elevation gradient (X = bird species, Y = elevation).

| siteID | BirdA | BirdB | BirdC | elevation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 275 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 550 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 850 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 322 |

My problem is that the bird data is count data. For example, site1 might have three pairs of Bird A, two pairs of Bird B and zero pairs of Bird C which makes the boxplotting somehow difficult. The boxplot command creates different boxes for sites with different amount of observations (own box for zero observations, one observation, two observations, three observations, etc.).

I want just one box for each bird species and I would like the boxplot to notice the sites/elevations with **several** pairs of certain bird species since it gives a clue of the optimal elevation for that certain bird species. I could change the count data in to presence-absence, but it alters my results.

I found out that the solution would be to change a row with three observations of BirdA into three rows with one observation of BirdA in a certain elevation. Is there a command or package that would help me change my data from count data to binomial form? Or is there an easier way of boxplotting these values?

Comment: Would you please explain a little more about your desired output? You need one boxplot per the type of Bird indicating the distribution of counts and how would you like to incorporate the elevation factor?

Comment: I'm looking to have one boxplot per the type of bird indicating the distribution of the elevation factor. I'm not interested in distribution of counts if you understand what I mean? Here is a link with an example of what I'm looking for: https://imgur.com/a/bYuZl25

Comment: The problem is if I reshape the data so that we have 3 rows for each unique site id and each row with one type of bird, each type of bird got the same elevation so the distribution of elevations per bird remain the same for them. I can't think of any other way to have distinct elevation values for each bird type.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that in this setting box plotting is appropriate as [Anoushiravan R mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931471/boxplotting-count-data-with-continuous-variable-in-r#comment118311549_66931471) in the comments. Moreover, I hope the solution here is a little help:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(fill=siteID, y=Count, x=Bird)) +
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_grid( ~ elevation)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Anoushiravan R and TarJae. This helped me greatly in giving me idea how to and how not to present my data.